# Language codes to friendly names

Tags: swift, macos, localization

I have a language code, such as "en_US", and I'm trying to get a friendly name from it such as "English".

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
Locale.current.localizedString(forLanguageCode: code)
```

It works, but for languages such as Chinese, it doesn't quite do what I want.

`zh-Hans` should return "Simplified Chinese", and `zh-Hant` should return "Traditional Chinese".

However, they both just return "Chinese". How would you get them to return the correct values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSLocale's [`displayName(forKey:value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1415931-displayname) instead.

```
let code = "en_US"
if let identifier = (Locale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .identifier, value: code) {
    print(identifier) /// English (United States)
}
```

```
let code = "zh_Hans"
if let identifier = (Locale.current as NSLocale).displayName(forKey: .identifier, value: code) {
    print(identifier) /// Chinese, Simplified
}
```

Comment: I believe using [`localizedString(forIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293562-localizedstring) function of `Locale` is the more Swiftier way.

Answer (score 3):

`"en_US"` is not a language code, it's a locale identifier consisting of the language code `"en"` and the region code `"US"`. Thus, calling into `localizedString(forLanguageCode:)` will not work properly. With an identifier (like you have), use [`localizedString(forIdentifier:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/2293562-localizedstring):

```
let identifier = "en_US"
let humanReadableName = 
    Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: identifier) ?? identifier
```

This also works nicely with identifiers such as `zh-Hans` which will return "Chinese, Simplified".

Note that I'm suggesting to append `?? identifier` at the end because `localizedString(forIdentifier:)` returns an Optional in case of an invalid identifier where you can fall back to the identifier itself so you don't have to deal with an Optional String.